How to ensure updated data with PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock without using EntityManager.refresh?
I’m having an issue with a Hibernate query where I need to use a PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock. The lock works fine in concurrent transactions, but the information returned by the query is outdated. To ensure the data is up-to-date, I have to call a refresh on the EntityManager, which I would prefer to avoid.
Here is the code I'm using:
public Account findByCodeWithLock(String code) throws Exception {
    TypedQuery<Account> query = em.createQuery("select a from Account a where a.accountCode = :code", Account.class);
    query.setParameter("code", code);
    query.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    logger.info("lock");
    Account account = query.getSingleResult();
    logger.info("getSingleResult: {}", account.getBalanceAmount());
    em.refresh(account);
    logger.info("refresh: {}", account.getBalanceAmount());
    return account;
}

I've also tried using some hints, such as:
query.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", false);
query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", CacheStoreMode.REFRESH);
query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS);

However, I haven't been successful. How can I get up-to-date data?
Note: I am using Java 8 with an Oracle database.
I attempted to use the PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock to ensure data consistency in concurrent transactions. I also tried various Hibernate hints to manage data freshness, but none of these methods resolved the issue. I expected that using the PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock would automatically keep the data up-to-date and avoid the need to manually call EntityManager.refresh to synchronize the entity state.

I can't find mention of a refresh query hint in hibernate (EclipseLink has https://eclipse.dev/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/q_refresh.htm). The storeMode/retrieveMode hints are only for the second level cache, not the managed entity (1st level) cache, which must have your entity loaded already. You could try evicting the entity and then fetching it. Hopefully someone else might have a mechanism to hijack and set a refresh option on a query in what ever way the refresh call does it.
